# Segmentation Fault using SQLite3 with C

Tags: c, sqlite, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a C program work and I'm getting mad. This is my code simplified to find the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(){
    sqlite3 *conn;
    sqlite3_stmt *res;
    const char *tail, *sqlresult;
    sqlite3_open("cubecat", &conn);
    char buffer,query;
    int id;

    id= 1;
    buffer = 'a';
    if(buffer == 'a') snprintf(&query,100,"SELECT start FROM payloads WHERE id=%d", id);

    printf("%s",&query);
    int error = sqlite3_prepare_v2(conn, &query, 100, &res, &tail);
    printf("%d",error);
}
```

The error is exactly on "sqlite_prepare_v2" function, because if I comment that line, there's no Segmentation Fault.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A `char *` is not necessarily a pointer to one `char`. It might be a pointer to the first element of a `char` **array.**

Comment: query as `char`? maybe it must be `char *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char query;
snprintf(&query,100,"SELECT start FROM payloads WHERE id=%d", id);
```

This is what's wrong. `query` only reserves memory for one character. There's a reason the 2nd argument of `snprintf()` specifies the size. This code should be modified like this:

```
char query[100];
snprintf(query, sizeof(query), "SELECT start FROM payloads WHERE id=%d", id);
```

Comment: I love Undefined Behavior :(
It is necessary to take out the & in front of query, because it doesn't work with them.